# CloudFlare is blocking Let's Encrypt renewal and setup

Tags: cloudflare, lets-encrypt

I use the Let's Encrypt SSL certificate server-side and also have my site set up to go through CloudFlare.

How can I make this work?

(I totally know the answer now, but thought I'd create a question/answer in case others have the same issue.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CloudFlare, set

**Crypto** > "Always Use HTTPS" > Off

I'm not sure what you can do if you need this on. I do my http > https redirect server-side (Apache). I actually never did try it set to On so maybe Let's Encrypt renewal will also work that way...

**Page Rules** >

- example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/*
- Settings: Browser Integrity Check: Off

and

- www.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/*
- Settings: Browser Integrity Check: Off

(Or whatever your subdomains are.)